# php mess detector and 2 warnings I don't understand

Tags: php, lint

I have a small php code written using brackets and it goes something like this:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'URL');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
if (strPos($content, 'content1') == 0 && strpos($content, 'content2') > 0) {
    $content = strstr($content, 'content2');
    while (strpos($content, '<tr><td>') > 0) {
    ...
    }
}
```

When lint is running, I get 2 issues:

1) "End of line character is invalid; expected "\n" but found "\r\n"" for the first line with "?php". I couldn't understand why it insists on this just for this line and how can I change the end of line character to something else.

2) PHP mess detector - Stack Trace: for the line `$content = strstr($content, 'content2');` . What mess am I causing with this line and how can I clean it?

Thanks

Comment: About number 1: What editor are you using? Maybe you can try "find and replace"  to replace "\r\n" for "\n" or something specific to your editor. On Eclipse you can use "File > Convert Line Delimiters To > Unix"

Comment: `I couldn't understand why it insists on this just for this line`.... it doesn't, it's just polite enough to mention it only once per file rather than repeating it for every single line in that file

Comment: Thanks @marcellorvalle but I'm using brackets. I don't have such option as eclipse. When searching for \r it doesn't find it ofcourse, it's not a "real" character.

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker , so once I will fix the first line, it will go on and on? well, lets fix the first one first :)

Comment: Fix them all in one go - most IDEs/editors have an option to set all line endings

Comment: Apparently not in brackets

Comment: @amos It don't need to be real characters. If Bracket have the option to do regex based search/replace you can do it (just tested on Sublime). Try using sublime as an second option, you can open the file inside it, do the search/replace, save and get back do Brackets.

Comment: I do have regexp searches but when trying different variations it didn't find \r or \n. Your sublime idea was OK if I needed a one time fix. I wanted to use sublime in general but I understood it costs money and is no under development anymore